# Unable to decode Base-64 URLs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, base64, url-encoding

I have an application that builds an HTML email.  Included in the content is an encoded URL parameter that might, for example, contain a promotional code or product reference.  The email is generated by a Windows service (essentially a console application) and the link, when clicked is handled by an MVC web site.  Here is the code for creating the email link:

```
string CreateLink(string domain, string code) {
    // code == "xyz123"
    string encrypted = DES3Crypto.Encrypt(code);  // H3uKbdyzrUo=
    string urlParam = encrypted.EncodeBase64();   // SDN1S2JkeXpyVW890
    return domain + "/" + urlParam;
}
```

The action method on the MVC controller is constructed as follows:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id) {
    string decoded = id.DecodeBase64();
    string decrypted = DES3Crypto.Decrypt(decoded);
    ...
}
```

In all our testing, this mechanism has worked as expected, however, now we have gone live we are seeing around a 4% error rate where the conversion from base-64 fails with the following exception:

*The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters.*

The id parameter from the url 'looks' OK.  The problem appears to be with the EncodeBase64/DecodeBase64 methods that are failing as DecodeBase64 method returns a 'garbled' string such as "�nl����□��7y�b�8�sJ���=" on the failed links.

Furthermore, most of the errors are from IE6 user agents leading me to think this is a character encoding problem but I don't see why.

For reference, here is the code for my base-64 URL encoding:

```
  public static string EncodeBase64(this string source)
  {
     byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source);
     string encodedString = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(bytes);
     return encodedString;
  }

  public static string DecodeBase64(this string encodedString)
  {
     byte[] bytes = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode(encodedString);
     string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
     return decodedString;
  }
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would log the "id" value in your controller when you get the exception to see if you can spot a pattern. My guess is that the id that comes to you has some invalid characters or was truncated (perhaps by the users' mail client)

Comment: Hi Hector, I've been doing that, but I can't see any obvious problems with the strings - here is an example "ywhar0xznxpjdnfnddc0yxzbk2jnqt090" of a string that fails.  One thing I have noticed is that the majority of user agents are being reported as IE6.0 - but I don't see why this should be the case.

Comment: I think I may have found the problem!  IE6 (or its associated email client) appears to be converting the url to lower-case - when encoded using base-64 derivative encoding, upper and lower-case characters have a different meaning, hence the problem when decoding on the web site.  So, I just need to find a way of encoding the url using only lowercase alpha-numeric characters!  Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recap, I was creating a URL that used a base-64 encoded parameter which was itself a Triple DES encrypted string.  So the URL looked like http://[Domain_Name]/SDN1S2JkeXpyVW890  The link referenced a controller action on an MVC web site.

The URL was then inserted into an HTML formatted email.  Looking at the error log, we saw that around 5% of the public users that responded to the link were throwing an "invalid base-64 string error".  Most, but not all, of these errors were related to the IE6 user agent.

After trying many possible solutions based around character and URL encoding, it was discovered that somewhere in the client's process the url was being converted to lower-case - this, of course, broke the base-64 encoding (as it is uses both upper and lower case encoding characters).

Whether the case corruption was caused by the client's browser, email client or perhaps local anti-virus software, I have not been able to determine.

**The Solution**
Do not use any of the standard base-64 encoding methods, instead use a base-32 or zBase-32 encoding instead - both of which are case-insensitive.

See the following links for more details

[Base-32 - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32)

[MyTenPennies Base-32 .NET Implementation](http://mytenpennies.wikidot.com/blog%3abase-32-encoder)

The moral of the story is, Base-64 URL encoding can be unreliable in some public environments.  Base-32, whilst slightly more verbose, is a better choice.

Hope this helps.

Comment: We've also seen Base-64 data being sometimes converted to lowercase. Haven't been able to isolate what is causing this (email client or browser?)

Comment: We have been running the code with ZBase-32 encoding for a couple of years now and it has been very reliable -  see http://mytenpennies.wikidot.com/blog:base-32-encoder

Comment: In overview we use TripleDES to encrypt the value and then encode using ZBase32.  At the other end we reverse the process decode ZBase-32 and the decrypt the result with TripleDES.  To make life easy, we created a couple of string extension methods ToZBase32() FromZBase32().

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you were really close. You had an extra zero coming back from your `encyrpted.EncodeBase64()` function.

Try this:

```
string data = "H3uKbdyzrUo=";
string b64str = Convert.ToBase64String(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
string clearText = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(b64str));
```

Comment: I originally used Convert.ToBase64String methods but they suffered the same problem when used as part of the URL.  I changed to HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode in the hope that it would fix the problem but in fact doesn't seem to have made any difference.  Neither method appears to use anything but plain alpha-numerics, so I can't figure out where/why the URL is being changed.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting issue. My guess is that IE 6 is eating some of the characters.

For example, the length of the string that you included "ywhar0xznxpjdnfnddc0yxzbk2jnqt090" **is not** a multiple of four (which is a requirement for FromBase64 to work http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx)

But if you were to pad that string until it's length is a multiple of four ("ywhar0xznxpjdnfnddc0yxzbk2jnqt090" + "a12") then that works.

The MSDN documentation says that one ("=") or two ("==") equal characters are used for padding to/fromBase64 methods and I suspect IE 6 is truncating that from the string that you send.

This is total speculation but I hope it helps.

Comment: Maybe, but I can't see why...  The HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode() method is supposed to use only plain alpha-numeric characters so while the url is non-English it is not 'unusual' if you see what I mean? http://[my_domain]/SDN1S2JkeXpyVW890 isn't even that long.