# Does AspNet automatically decode url?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I encode strings using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(str)`.

And I have a method that receives that string via `GET`, like this:

```
public ActionResult Confirm(string id)
{
    // ...
}
```

`id` is the encoded string received like this:

> http://[mysite].com/[ctrler]/Confirm?id=[TheStringEncoded]

Inside `Confirm` method, I put a `HttpUtility.UrlDecode(id)`, but then it starts to produce errors because the id seems already decoded.

Is the default behavior of asp.net to url decode these params? I'm a bit afraid of its use now, what if it changes depending on some server configuration (I'm wondering), what if some produced string need to decode and others don't? Shall I use `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` here or not?

**PS:** the string encoded is in base64. Can I pass that base64 string within `?id=` without `UrlEncode`?

Answer (score 3):

If I recall my MVC correctly, you should encode from the client side.  The parameter in the controller method is going to expect clean input.  I never had to decode within the controller method.

Comment: the string encoded is in base64. Can I pass that base64 in `?id=` without encode?

Comment: @Fabricio See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828864/unable-to-decode-base-64-urls?rq=1 It looks like you should be able to do it.